# Unity не видит пространство имен Microsoft

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу писать логи в Word'овский документ, но столкнулся с проблемой следующего плана. VS на ссылку

> using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

не ругается, а вот сам Unity пишет в консоль следующее - Assets/ToWord.cs(3,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Office' does not exist in the namespace`Microsoft'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: а зачем вам именно вордовский документ? Вы собираетесь использовать спец функционал и шифрование или просто хотите, чтобы ваш файл с логами открывался в ворде? Если вариант второй, то вы можете просто сохраняя файл задавать ему в имени .doc и вам не придётся тянуть с собой никаких дополнительных библиотек, увеличивая размер сборки и сложность кода.

Comment: @M. Green, Мне нужно выводить формализованный отчёт о результате работы программы.

Answer (score 1):

[Что такое NuGet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget)

---

Как пользоваться NuGet в Visual Studio:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть небольшая проблема. На том ПК нет подключения к интернету.

Comment: И Interop.Word прикручен, иначе ругался бы сам VS

Comment: Попробуйте подключить как dll. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

Comment: Поставил в настройках плеера .Net 4.6, в VS из NuGet поставил Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Unity ругается до сих пор.

Comment: нет, уже все возможные библиотеки поставил в VS. Надо что-то в Unity крутить, а что не знаю...

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось в следующем -

В VS в проект добавляем ссылки на:

1. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
2. Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll
3. office.dll
4. stdole.dll

Эти же библиотеки кидаем в папку Assets вашего проекта.